# how to pass compiler options to mocha

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js

I run a mocha command to run my tests

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script -R spec
```

I wish to pass additional options to the coffee-script compiler (--bare to avoid the outer closure that is introduced when compiling .coffee to .js). Is there a way to do this? I tried

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script --bare -R spec
```

but that doesn't look right. It also failed saying that --bare is not a valid option for mocha.

```
  error: unknown option `--bare'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The --compiler option doesn't support this, but you can write a script which activates the compiler with your options, then use mocha's --require  option to activate your registration script.  For example, create a file at the root of the project called babelhook.js:

```
// This file is required in mocha.opts
// The only purpose of this file is to ensure
// the babel transpiler is activated prior to any
// test code, and using the same babel options

require("babel-register")({
  experimental: true
});
```

Then add this to mocha.opts:

```
--require babelhook
```

And that's it.  Mocha will require babelhook.js before any tests.

Comment: isn't it babel-register?

Comment: @goldylucks I believe `babel/register` is Babel v5, `babel-register` Babel v6.

Answer (score 27):

Simply add a `.babelrc` file to your root.
Then any instances of babel (build, runtime, testing, etc) will reference that.
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

You can even add specific config options per-environment.

Comment: This seems like the best solution

Comment: Hm, I think I can't modify the "ignore" option for babel-register via the .babelrc, but if I use the babelhook way then it works.

Comment: The `ignore` option currently does not seem to work in `.babelrc` https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone stumbles upon this. The 'experimental' option in babel has been deprecated. Your 'babelhook.js' should now read:

```js
// This file is required in mocha.opts
// The only purpose of this file is to ensure
// the babel transpiler is activated prior to any
// test code, and using the same babel options

require("babel/register")({
  stage: 1
});
```