# Handle WebPack CSS imports when testing with Mocha and Babel

Tags: javascript, css, mocha.js, webpack, babeljs

When testing `.js` files that have Webpack CSS imports like `import './style.css'`, Mocha throws a syntax error (because it tries to import and parse the CSS file as JS). There is a solution for this [that has already been posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683440/handle-webpack-css-imports-when-testing-with-mocha), but it only addresses if you aren't already using a compiler with Mocha. I'm using Babel 5. I've tried the following, but it seems that Mocha doesn't support passing multiple compilers:

```
// npm test script

mocha ./src/**/*Test.js --compilers css:./scripts/mocha-webpack-compiler.js js:babel/register

// scripts/mocha-webpack-compiler.js

function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
```

Is there a way to have multiple Mocha compilers, or a better way to tell Mocha not to try to parse Webpack CSS imports?

---

EDIT:

I like the proposed solution by @Giles B below; it was exactly what I needed. However, since I am still on Babel 5 I needed a few tweaks as shown below:

## mocha.opts

```
--require scripts/support/babelhook
--require scripts/support/mocha-webpack-compiler
```

## scripts/babelhook.js

```
require('babel/register');
```

## scripts/mocha-webpack-compiler.js

```
function noop() {
    return null;
}
require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
```

## mocha script

```
mocha ./src/**/*Test.js
```

This is working for me using `babel` and `babel-core`, both version `5.8.23`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I came across the same problem and just got it working, so in my mocha.opts file I added the following `require` calls:

```
--require test/babelhook
--require test/css-null-compiler
```

In `babelhook.js` I have one require statement to load babel:

```
// This file is required in mocha.opts
// The only purpose of this file is to ensure
// the babel transpiler is activated prior to any
// test code, and using the same babel options

require("babel-register")();
```

Then from the link you [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683440/handle-webpack-css-imports-when-testing-with-mocha) I setup `css-null-compiler.js` as follows:

```
// Prevent Mocha from compiling class
function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
require.extensions['.scss'] = noop;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you - this looks to be exactly what I need. But, it isn't working for me yet: I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"; are you using ES6 modules? Btw, I am still on Babel 5 (babel 6 had too many issues currently).

Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049790/how-to-pass-compiler-options-to-mocha

Comment: I've also added a bounty of 100 reputation if you or anyone else can help me get this working

Comment: Hey @trevordmiller, sorry for the late reply. Yes I'm using Babel 6 so maybe that is where the problem is. I'm testing ES6 modules but the code above isn't ES6.

Comment: I think require("babel-register")(); is only for Babel 6, you need require("babel/register"); for version 5.

Comment: I tried using require('babel/register'); instead, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I think I may have solved it - I didn't realize that mocha.opts needed to be in /test/ in order to be recognized (I had it in the root of the project). I will do more testing and get back; if it is working, I will award the bounty points to you Giles.

Comment: Now I am getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` error again, but for a different reason; it looks like `babel/register` doesn't work with import statements inside of `node_modules/` packages. Odd, because all of my tests were working with the `--compilers` option from the direct CLI. I'm not sure what to do now. I could use the Webpack --target node option in the webpack docs, but I would prefer to have my tests work without any dependency on Webpack.

Comment: This is an unrelated problem - it is working for what I asked, so I will award Giles the bounty. Thanks Giles!

Comment: Note that you don't need mocha.opts. And you don't need two separate files either. You could simply call a single file from the command line which contains both the babel and null compiler code. Here's how I solved it: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/package.json#L18

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Giles' answer above, this is what I used to get working on Babel 6

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register 
          --require ./tools/testHelper.js 'src/**/*-spec.@(js|jsx)'",
```

**tools/testHelper.js**

```
// Prevent mocha from interpreting CSS @import files
function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
```

This enables you to have your tests inside your src folder alongside your components.